# Suddenly I cannot debug anything in VS2010

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

Since yesterday I cannot debug and step into any source code in VS2010. It is displaying the text as shown in the screenshot below. Whenever click on *"Browse to Find Source"* The text changes to the following:

> No source available.  The source code
>   cannot be displayed.

The funny thing about this screenshot is that it states that it actually **could** find the correct source file with the correct checksum.

What could have happend here and how do I fix it?

In the example below I have setup a simple windows forms application project and set a breakpoint in the form's constructor and then hit f5.

**Update:** When I start the application separately and then attach to it later, everything works fine. I can hit the breakpoints.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe a filesystem issue ? I mean no free space, security issue ?

Comment: There is enough space and I am not aware of any changes in my file system since yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this happend but resetting the visual studio settings did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it in Release mode possibly, with the PDBs disabled/ turned-off?

Also, try running it (outside the debugger) and attaching to the process.